# Doxygen alternative for Verilog, SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, doxygen, fpga, system-verilog, asic

Project "doxverilog" is not supported more, author's site is not responding. Project http://intelligentdv.com/downloads/index.html#doxygentools works only for SV class hierarchy. AMIQ http://www.dvteclipse.com/ Specador is enterprise overpriced product.
What to use?

Answer (score 4):

Natural Docs is being used by the UVM community. https://verificationacademy.com/forums/downloads/naturaldocs-html-documentation-generator

Answer (score 2):

For anybody looking to generate documentation for Verilog or SystemVerilog, I would recommend taking a look at the [IDV doxygen filter](https://github.com/SeanOBoyle/DoxygenFilterSystemVerilog) noted in the original question. It is not limited to classes - I found it to be a viable option in its current state and think it also has a lot of potential.

To better understand the potential - I am currently using this (with a few minor custom hacks) to document an FPGA project written in SystemVerilog. The script works by attempting to translate the HDL into something that can be parsed as if it were C++. For example, my project primarily documents modules, interfaces and structures. The structs are handled just like they are in C\C++ and the modules and interfaces are both handled by translating these into functions, where the ports are documented as [@param](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdparam) entries and the redefinable parameters are documented as [@tparam](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdtparam) entries. When the code is then run through doxygen via this filter, the result is that each module and interface is documented as a function with the description, the definitions for the ports (parameters) and descriptions of the redefinable parameters (template parameters). This is a great start, but there's room for improvement. For example, the module instantiations are not currently recognized as function calls, so doxygen does not generate a call graph representing the hierarchy of instantiations. However, this seems like a feasible enhancement.

Note that I linked to the Github repository for the project. The author does not appear to be actively maintaining the project, but maybe if we all start making contributions this can grow into something that will fully meet the need.